# Can someone explaint what this code do?

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out what this code but no luck. I need some explanations

```
signed char c = '0';
for(; c > 0; c++);
printf("%d", c);
```

output is -128, when I change the sign to "less then" output is 48, why?

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Think about the size of a `char` and think about the sign bit.

Comment: It's impossible to reliably answer the question _"why?"_. Theoretically, you could end up [formatting your hard drive](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/05/19/undefined-behavior-can-format-your-drive/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) Encoding of characters, 
you can see that the character `'0'` has the numerical value `48`.

The `for`loop will continue as long `c` is positive. After every iteration it will be incremented by 1. `signed char` holds values from -128 to 127.
If 127 gets incremented you get undefined behaviour as stated in the C standard. So you should never do, except if you just play around. Possible things that can reasonably happen are:

- A wrap around to -128
- An infinite loop because the compiler thinks that a wrap around can not happen so he assumes `c>0` is always true.

There might be other things (its undefined), but in your case the wrap around happens and `c` is -128.

If you change the relation to `c<0` he the condition is `false`from the beginning and the loop will be skipped, giving you 48 as the answer.

Comment: ahh, I see, didn't thought about that, thank you, this can solve many problems

Comment: The answer does state it, but let me do so again to be super clear: DO NOT RELY on this behaviour.